# WP7.1 Compass: is it mandatory to call stop?

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

If I have an app using the compass in such a way:

```
if (Compass.IsSupported)
            {
                Compass c = new Compass();
                c.CurrentValueChanged += (s, e) =>
                    {

                        Heading = e.SensorReading.TrueHeading;
                        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Heading"));
                    };
                c.Start();
            }
```

Is it mandatory to call somewhere the Stop(), or does the sensor reading automatically stops when the app close?
I just don't want to create a battery sinker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to call stop but you probably should. It will be stopped when your app is switched/tombstoned/closed.

You're desire to not create a "create a battery sinker" contradicts the need for your question. A great rule of thumb is if you don't need it you should stop it.
If you're not using it on every page of your app it will probably only be appropriate to have it running when it's needed/used.

Comment: The app is single page now, so I suppose it is reasonable not to stop

Comment: @FelicePollano Ok, just be careful about restarting after FAS & tombstoning. It'll probably be simpler overall if you stop it when navigating from the page and restart it when navigating back.

Comment: thanks, it's probably that I'm not used to mobile developement, I should learn more: any good best practice reference ?